# How to make an drawing sketch of the Godzilla heat beam, without leaving a trace of the beam line?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, draw, p5.js

```js
let drawing = [];
let city;

function preload() {
  city = loadImage("city.jpg");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(city.width, city.height);
}

function mouseDragged() {
  drawing.push({
    mouseX: mouseX,
    mouseY: mouseY,
  });
}

function draw() {
  colorMode(HSB);

  // clear previous frame
  background(city);

  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    // set line color to a range from light yellow to dark red
    // using HSB color mode with hue from 40 to 0 and saturation and brightness at 100
    stroke(random(0, 40), 100, 100);

    // draw line from top right corner to mouse y-5 and y+5
    line(width - 1, 0, mouseX, mouseY - 5);
    line(width - 1, 0, mouseX, mouseY + 5);

    line(width - 1, 0, mouseX + random(-5, 5), mouseY + random(-5, 5));

    // set fill color to random
    fill(random(0, 40), 100, 100);

    // generate a random position within a radius of 10 of the mouse position
    let x = mouseX + random(-20, 20);
    let y = mouseY + random(-20, 20);

    // draw a circle of radius 1 at the random position
    circle(x, y, 2);
  }
}
```

https://editor.p5js.org/106p01013/sketches/dgE9njGLj

I want to use the mouse to control Godzilla's heat beam and burn down the city for painting.
However, every time I try to make a paint mark, the effects of the beam line are left in the canvas.

How can I paint with airbrush effects without letting the beam line have a trace?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.